# Is it possible to remove extra space only for Chinese character but keep necessary code symbol in html?

Tags: html

I want to update the page so all the sentences in Chinese all contain extra spaces and every Chinese character gets a space before it.

The page will be a mess if I press `\S` to find all the all extra space, then delete all.

It will take lot of time pressing `\S` to find all the all extra space in the code, then cut out the specific Chinese character one by one.

[image: extra spaces remove]

Answer (score 0):

(I just saw that you are doing it in an editor. The following is in JavaScript. You can install Node.js and write a simple program to read in each line and replace it with the correct content, write it back out to a file. For example, Google for `Node fs`.)

You could use:

```js
const s = "Oscar list 奧 斯 卡 提 名 名 單 出 爐 - 最   佳   導演全男班 today";

const result = s.replace(/([^\u0000-\u00FF])[ \t]*(?![\u0000-\u00FF])/gu, "$1");

console.log(result);

// stringify to show string:

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Basically it is saying, if it is not the usual 8-bit extended ASCII but is unicode character `$1`, followed by some space, and it is not 8-bit extended ASCII afterwards (just lookahead), then replace it with just `$1`.

You can change it to 7-bit ASCII if you want, which is `[^\u0000-\u007F]`